# is it possible to run sql query statement with Integer.parseInt

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

I am trying to do a droplist that would show specific data in a list if user select either of type in the droplist. I have been getting error for the sql query. Here are the code i have created:

```
Class.forName("xxx").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxserverTimezone=Singapore", "xxx", "xxx");

String SQLQuery1 = ("SELECT Model,Brand,IMEI, YearManufactured, Country FROM initprinter where PID = " + Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("test")));
                        PreparedStatement PS1 = con.prepareStatement(SQLQuery1);
                        ResultSet RS1 = PS1.executeQuery();
```

I'm trying to show specific type of printer and their details in a table for output but all i get is Http status 500 error and error location located at the String query statement.

Comment: Please learn to properly use a PreparedStatement with placeholders (`?`)  rather than concatenating values into the SQL string. Additionally: you should **not** run SQL statements within a JSP page. And you should not manually create connections through the DriverManager in a web application. Use a connection pool and do that processing in a Servlet or a custom JSP tag.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok. I will try to do it

Answer (score 0):

Your `query` should be like below :

```
String SQLQuery1 = "SELECT Model,Brand,IMEI, YearManufactured, Country FROM initprinter where PID = '"+ Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("test")) +"'";
```

Also i suggest you to used `Prepared statement` like below :

```
   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select Model,Brand,IMEI, YearManufactured, Country FROM initprinter where PID =?");
  ps.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("test")));//setting parameter for ID=?
 ResultSet resultset= ps.executeQuery();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have use ur method and still unable. Guess i have to find another way :(

Comment: see `updated` answer and check once , also if still any error occur tell me .

Comment: used the updated and still got error. Need help and it is giving me a headache....

Comment: it says the error is located at >"PS1.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("test"))); and also status 500 internal server error"

Comment: first check that `request.getParameter("test")` has some value in or not , also is your `pid` column is `integer` type?